# Is there any java based template engine to parse dynamic messages like apache vm does for generation?

Tags: java, apache, velocity

Hi i am working in an java application which needs to extract some info/data from a some fixed structure messages. For example;

```
The price of mango is Rs.10
```

The message structre will be always in the format:

```
The price of $item is Rs. $amt
```

Is there is framework any java which can read/parse the item and amt if the structure is specified like For generation of such messages apache velocity mapping is used..

Message+MsgStrucrte in template = amt and item.

Comment: Why close voting??If the answer is available in any link please post the link.I searched everywhere couldnt find any.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, yes, there is one. I coded a parser using the same syntax (and based upon) Apache Velocity, back in 2007.

I uploaded it to github, codename [stillness](https://github.com/cbrisson/stillness).

The documentation is minimalist, but examples in the README should be enough.